# How to make a css transition from background size cover to 105% 105%?

Tags: html, css, image

In css3, I have this

https://codepen.io/sneaky666/pen/poyxxZY

```
<div id="pic">
  
</div>
```

css

```
#pic {
  background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542362567-b07e54358753?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80');
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  /*background-size:cover;*/
  background-position: center;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.5s;
}
#pic:hover {
    background-size:105% 105%;
}
```

And this scales the BG size from 100% to 105% which looks nice. However I want the initial size to be `cover`. But if I do that, it doesn't smoothly transition from `cover` to `105% 105%`. How can I still do this?

Thanks

Comment: the only way is to increase the container size via transform:scale(1.05) and set an overflw:hidden on the parent :)  ... so that makes 2 container .. div > img ? instead div + style bg

Comment: can you show an example code?

Comment: `<div id="pic"><img></div>` img gets the background and object-fit rule, then scales on hover while div has overflow:hidden; ;)

Comment: with an `img` tag, how do you use `cover`?

Comment: see the doc  :)   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit  same value for the rule ;)  `div,img {height:200px;width:200px;object-fit:cover;}`

Answer (score 1):

Think about it differently and instead of changing the `background-size`, you change the reference used to calculate the size. You make your `background-origin` equal to `content-box` and use `box-sizing: border-box`. By adjusting the padding you increase/decrease the content area and you keep the same size of your element. We also add a small `clip-path` to hide the overflow:

```css
.pic {
  background: 
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/400)
      center/cover content-box  no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: padding 0.5s;
  /* adjust the below */
  padding: 10px; /* 10px = 200px*0.05 */
  clip-path:inset(10px);
}

.pic:hover {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">

</div>

<div class="pic" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/17/400/800)">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use an `<img>` tag, , [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)  and `transform:scale(x)` **instead** `background`/`background-size`;

example:

```css
#pic , #pic img{ 
  width:200px;
  height:200px; 
  object-fit:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img {transition:0.25s}
#pic:hover img {
   transform:scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div id="pic">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542362567-b07e54358753?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
</div>
```

`background-size: calc(cover * 1.05) ;` is not avalaible unfortunately ;) , you have to think it otherwise.